# Cant find root elements with RemoteWebDriver.FindElementsByXPath("/");

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

When I try to use

```
var element = webdriver.FindElementByXPath("/");
```

or

```
var elements = webdriver.FindElementsByXPath("/");
```

I expect to get the root element(s) of my document.

What I get instead is an InvalidSelectorException with this message.

> "invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "/" is: [object
>   HTMLDocument]. It should be an element.   (Session info:
>   chrome=50.0.2661.102)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459
>   (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 10.0
>   x86_64)"

Why? Is there some way of getting that `HTMLDocument` object or as I initially wanted, the root element(s)?

Isnt the xpath `/` the root element (instead of document)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/` references *root node*, i.e the document node. And as the method name suggests, it only capable of returning *element*, not arbitrary kind of node.

To get *root element* of the document, you can use `/*` instead :

```
var element = webdriver.FindElementByXPath("/*");
```